# Is it reasonable to access the DB from inside an Automapper TypeConverter?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, anti-patterns

So I have come across some code in the code base I'm working on.

We are using Automapper to map from domain objects (Poco/dto's) to Entity Framework Models. This is all good.

However in some of the mappers we have are using an implementation on `ITypeConverter` which is instantiated with a instance of our EF dbcontext. Which is used to look up things like IDs for a given string.

This feels like a code smell to me (but obviously my colleagues think it's cool).

**Is it a good or bad idea to be accessing the DB inside a Automapper TypeConverter?**

Comment: Probably a bit of a subjective question, but personally I only rely on Automapper to go from Entity to DTO, never DTO to Entity. I am wary of having any code attempting to automagically copy across data into entity references. When it is explicitly done it is very much there and visible for people to review exactly what and when entity values are being updated. Whenever an unexpected entity change happens, one of the first checks is a find-usages on the property in question. These are masked if you use Automapper to update entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered one reason why it is a bad idea.

If one mapping makes a call tho the db, well you were going to have to make that call either way.

However if the mapper needs to map a collection of objects then the mapper is going to make N db calls. Which potentially be performed as a single call.